# How to input a date with a specific date format in struts 2.2.3.1?

Tags: java, struts2

I want to know if there is a way to force the input format for a date in struts, something like dd/MM/yyyy .
The date is written in a text field. I read that this is a locale sensitive subject, but it seems a too much to switch locales for a simple changing of format.
I know I could call `addFieldError(fieldName, errorMessage)` inside the method of my Action class but to me it feels like a date format should have been thought of to be configured in an Action-validation.xml file. I searched to configure this with properties file but found no working example. 
Is using a custom `StrutsTypeConverter` and `addFieldError(fieldName, errorMessage)` the only way to do it? Or is there another version of struts in which the date format inputed in a text field can be specified?
**UPDATE:**
I assumed I made myself clear enough but some answers demostrate otherwise.
The use case is: User enters manually a date in an arbitrary format in a textfield, afterwards struts2 validates the date format as corresponding to the format set by the programmer or not, displaying a message accordingly. 
A jQuery date picker with a `<s:date>` tag can be an alternative to what I want to achieve, but it it **NOT** what I asked. Furthermore, Javascript can be disabled, rendering the date picker useless, jQuery being a Javascript library as far as I understand it.

Comment: It depends on how do you enter date in the textfield and how this value is converted. Try the current version, or change the tag.

Comment: Don't see what you mean there, I wrote "The date is written in a text field." as an user input, manually. There's no other tag to change to (the `<s:date>` tag is only for display not for input).

Comment: @user2663337: Do you want to validate date?

Comment: I want to validate a date with a specified format as mentioned in the question "something like dd/MM/yyyy" another example would be: yyyy.dd.MM

Comment: And what would be the solution for what you want? Maybe you just need to write date format in JSP or create dropdowns with day/month/year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My action implemented `ModelDriven` but the date format can't be supplied anywhere to be forced in the text field, I did use my own validator, but I changed the mapping of the form element to be a `String` named in the action class, then used a validator with a `SimpleDateFormat` with the format retrieved from a resource bundle to convert it to a date, then formated the date again, to see if the representation is the same as the one inputed in the text field. Hardly after all that the format is clear.
 If there are other suggestions I welcome them, this seems like the only choice.
I find this drawback at the very least annoying.

Comment: It seems that what you have described is a converter not a validator.

Comment: It does convert the string, because that's the only way I found of being sure the format is what I want. A datepicker would have been what I needed if the text input field wouldn't have existed, anyway it's a validator that converts the text string.

Comment: You have sad that you want to validate inputs and there is my answer. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: I solved in the manner I answered, now I'm just waiting for a better answer or an improvement.

Comment: Improvement to what exactly? Of what drawback are you talking?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a specific format of date on your page, i will advise you to use `struts 2  jquery datepicker`. You can find a demo of this following [this url](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action). Go to `widgets` tab, select `datepicker`.